# set a div according to the img it contains

Tags: css

How can I set the size of a div automatically according to the img it contains?

```
<div id="img">
  <img src=""/>
</div>
```

this div will contain different imgs because they are fetches from database so I would adapt it

Comment: if you don't set a size at all, the div takes the size of it's child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply style

.img{
display: inline-block;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
.img{
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
width:auto;
}
```

You can also provide a `min-width` and `min-height` depending on your necessity

Comment: auto is the default for height/width. so it makes no sense to set it. and overflow hidden for height/width auto is also senseless, because there will never be an overflow

Comment: it will encompass the child.. so,`auto` .. without which it'll be `0` height.. !!